# Functionality for automatic retry after exception

Tags: java, android, abstract-class

I have made this abstract class to automatically retry network calls if some exception is thrown.

- I take care to not retry after `InterruptedException` &
  `UnknownHostException`.
- I retry 5 times.  After each failure
  I perform an exponential back off, starting from 300ms going upto
  1500ms.

```java
public abstract class AutoRetry {

  private Object dataToReturn = null;
  public Object getDataToReturn() {
    return this.dataToReturn;
  }

  public AutoRetry() {

    short retry = -1;
    while (retry++ < StaticData.NETWORK_RETRY) {

      try {
        Thread.sleep(retry * StaticData.NETWORK_CALL_WAIT);
        this.dataToReturn = doWork();
        break;
      } catch (InterruptedException | UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        this.dataToReturn = null;
        return;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  protected abstract Object doWork() throws IOException;
}
```

I use it as follows :

```js
final Object dataAfterWork = new AutoRetry() {     
  @Override
  protected Object doWork() throws IOException {
    return; //a network call which returns something
  }
}.getDataToReturn();
```

So is this implementation good/correct ?

---

### EDIT

moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87686

Comment: I would use `Java 8` lambdas - ask for a `Supplier<T>` and return `T`. This would drastically reduce boilerplate.

Comment: Good idea, but I cant use Java8. Its an android application. (Added the tag)

Comment: If your code is working I would advise you to head over code review here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: My code still, applies - use the anonymous class. Your method is somewhat unpleasant with the `null` and the assignment and the `break`. Also the generics in my approach are much cleaner than your `Object`.

Comment: My advice is to split the task from its execution; I would pass a Runnable or a Custom interface to AutoRetry; this decouples what you are doing from the retry policy

Comment: @Giovanni I think Boris's answer complies with your suggestion, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks pretty good, but I would split the running task from the retry. Also use generics, don't just throw `Object` about.

Use a `Java 8` lambda and the `return` of the method:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> doWithRetry(final Supplier<T> t) {
    for (int retry = 0; retry <= StaticData.NETWORK_RETRY; ++retry) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(retry * StaticData.NETWORK_CALL_WAIT);
            return Optional.of(t.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | UnknownHostException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Call failed.", e);
            return Optional.empty();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Call failed. Retry.", e);
        }
    }
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Call failed. Retries exceeded.");
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Also, use a **real** logger, not `printStackTrace`...

Usage:

```
final String data = doWithRetry(() -> {
   //do stuff 
});
```

If your lambda needs to throw an exception, you'll need to define your own `@FunctionalInterface`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface StuffDoer<T> {
    T doStuff() throws Exception;
}
```

And use that in the method signature, you'll need to handle generic `Exception`.

Pre-Java 8 usage:

```
final String data = doWithRetry(new StuffDoer<T>() {
    @Override
    public T get() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok I can use Guava versions of Optional and Supplier. What is wrong with printStackTrace ?

Comment: @Dexter it prints to STDOUT. You have no control over where its printed to and when its printed. Using STDOUT for logging is a sure sign of code not written in a professional environment.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But I am using Android Studio, even the Google tutorials had printStackTrace. (I can use Log in android)

Comment: My whole app has printStackTrace everywhere, should I consider changing this ?

Comment: Tutorials often do, because setting up a logging framework is complicated and not part of the tutorial. Using STDOUT _just works_ TM. Yes, I would consider changing it, because then you can turn off all your debug logging for deployment in production - you might not want people seeing the insides of your code.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I often missed a lot of stackTraces..hmm, ok got your point :)